# IE7 and CSS display properties

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

Here is some asp.net markup:

```
<tr style="display:none" id="AllInRateRow">
                    <td id="td6">
                            All-In Fixed Rate <span id="allInRateHelp" />
                    </td>
                    <td id="td7">
                        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FixedRate, new { @class = "economicTextBox", propertyName = "FixedRate", dontRegisterNewIndication = true })%> %
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr style="display:none" id="ProfitRow">
                    <td id="td93">
                        Your Swap Profit
                    </td>
                    <td id="yourSwapProfit">
                        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Fees.ProfitAmount, new { @class = "economicTextBox", propertyName = "Fees.ProfitAmount", dontRegisterNewIndication = true })%>
                            <%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Fees.ProfitType, (int)Chatham.Enumerations.IndicationProfitType.bps,
                                                    new { label = "bps", propertyName = "Fees.ProfitType", dontRegisterNewIndication = true })%>
                        bps
                        <%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Fees.ProfitType, (int)Chatham.Enumerations.IndicationProfitType.CurrencyAmount,
                                                                new { label = "$", propertyName = "Fees.ProfitType", dontRegisterNewIndication = true })%>
                        $
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

I think it's a problem with the display property for CSS. It doesn't display them on page load which is the correct thing, but then the selection of this is supposed to change that:

```
<td id="td4">
                        Options <span id="solverHelper" />
                    </td>
                    <td id="solveType">
                        <%=Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Fees.CalculationSource, DropDownData.SolverOptionsList(),
                                                                new { propertyName = "Fees.CalculationSource", dontRegisterNewIndication = true })%>
                    </td>
```

And those things happen through JQuery setting CSS and changing it like so:

```
    var pricingOptions = $("#Fees_CalculationSource").val();
            if(pricingOptions == <%= ((int)Chatham.Web.Models.Indications.SwapModel.SolverOptions.AllInRate).ToString() %>)
            {
                $("#AllInRateRow").css("display", "none");
                $("#ProfitRow").css("display", "table-row");
                if(canExcludeFees) $("#IncludeFeesOption").css("display", "table-row");
                else $("#IncludeFeesOption").css("display", "none");

            }
            else if (pricingOptions == <%= ((int)Chatham.Web.Models.Indications.SwapModel.SolverOptions.Profit).ToString() %>)
            {
                $("#AllInRateRow").css("display", "table-row");
                $("#ProfitRow").css("display", "none");
                $("#IncludeFeesOption").css("display", "table-row");
                if(canExcludeFees) $("#IncludeFeesOption").css("display", "table-row");
                else $("#IncludeFeesOption").css("display", "none");

            }
            else if (pricingOptions == <%= ((int)Chatham.Web.Models.Indications.SwapModel.SolverOptions.None).ToString() %>)
            {
                $("#AllInRateRow").css("display", "table-row");
                $("#ProfitRow").css("display", "none");
                $('input[propertyname=Fees.IncludeFeeIndicator]:eq(1)').attr('checked', 'checked');
                $(

"#IncludeFeesOption").css("display", "none");
        }
```

I think IE7 is unable to work with setting the CSS to the table-row property, but it does work with the 'none'.

Am I correct? And if I am, what would be a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly IE7 uses `display:block`. The easiest way to show the elements would be to just call the show/hide methods from jQuery instead of trying to control the display property yourself.

```
$("#AllInRateRow").show();
$("#ProfitRow").hide();
```

This will work in all browsers and you will not need to worry about browser specifics.